# What is the function to just identify outliers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I know of the `TRIMMEAN` function to help automatically exclude outliers from means, but is there one that will just identify which data points are true outliers? I am working under the classical definition of outliers being 3 SD away from the mean and in the bottom 25% and top 25% of data.

I need to do this in order to verify that my R code is indeed removing true outliers as we are defining them in my lab for our research purposes. R can be weird with the work arounds of identifying and removing outliers and since our data is mixed (we have numerical data grouped by factor classes) it gets to tricky to ensure that we are for sure identifying and removing outliers within those class groups. This is why we are turning to a spreadsheet program to do a double-check instead of assuming that the code is doing it correctly automatically.

Is there a specific outlier identification function in Google Sheets?

Data looks like this:

```
group   VariableOne   VariableTwo   VariableThree   VariableFour
NAC      21            17            0.9             6.48
GAD      21            17            -5.9            0.17
UG       40            20            -0.4            6.8
SP       20            18            -6              -3
NAC      19            4             -8              8.48
UG       18            10            0.1             -1.07
NAC      23            24            -0.2            3.5
SP       21            17            1               3.1
UG       21            17           -5               5.19
```

As stated, each data corresponds to a specific group code. That is to say, their data should be relatively similar within each group. My data as a whole does show this generally, but there are outliers within these groups which we want to exclude and I want to ensure we are excluding the correct data.

If I can get even more specific with the function and see outliers within the groups then great, but as long as I can identify outliers in Google Sheets that could suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the outliers, you must

1. Calculate first quartile (Q1): This can be done in sheets using `=Quartile(dataset, 1)`
2. Calculate third quartile (Q3): Same as number 1, but different quartile number `=Quartile(dataset, 3)`
3. Calculate interquartile range (IQR): `=Q3-Q1`
4. Calculate lower boundary LB: `=Q1-(1.5*IQR)`
5. Calculate upper boundary UB: `=Q3+(1.5*IQR)`

By getting the lower and upper boundary, we can easily determine which data in our datasets are outliers.

Example:

[image]

You can use Conditional formatting to highlight the outliers by clicking **Format**->**Conditional Formatting** and copy the following:

[image]

Click **Done** and the result should look like this:

[image]

### Reference:

- [QUARTILE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094041?hl=en)